Partial derivatives with respect to position of rate of change of distance (Euclidean norm) between two time-varying positions
I'm interested in the partial derivatives $$\frac{\partial d}{\partial p_x}, \frac{\partial d}{\partial p_y}, \frac{\partial d}{\partial p_z}\quad\text{,}\quad\frac{\partial\dot{d}}{\partial p_x}, \frac{\partial\dot{d}}{\partial p_y}, \frac{\partial\dot{d}}{\partial p_z}\quad,\ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \frac{\partial\dot{d}}{\partial \dot{p}_x}, \frac{\partial\dot{d}}{\partial \dot{p}_y}, \frac{\partial\dot{d}}{\partial \dot{p}_z}$$
where $p(t)=[p_x(t)\ \ p_y(t)\ \ p_z(t)]\in\mathbb{R}^3$ is a (column) vector of the first time-varying Euclidean position, $q(t)=[q_x(t)\ \ q_y(t)\ \ q_z(t)]\in\mathbb{R}^3$ is the same for the second position, $\dot{p}(t)=[\dot{p}_x(t)\ \ \dot{p}_y(t)\ \ \dot{p}_z(t)]\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\dot{q}(t)=[\dot{q}_x(t)\ \ \dot{q}_y(t)\ \ \dot{q}_z(t)]\in\mathbb{R}^3$ are their respective rates of change over time, the time-varying distance between the positions is $d(t) = \|p(t)-q(t)\|$, and from the accepted answer at Time derivative of the distance between 2 points moving over time we have the rate of change of that distance over time as $$\dot{d}\!(t) = \frac{p(t)-q(t)}{d(t)}\ \cdot\ (\dot{p}(t)-\dot{v}(t))$$
My attempt to find the partial derivatives uses the following three facts, which I believe are correct though I don't have sources for them:

for any vector $v=[v_1\ \cdots\ v_M]\in\mathbb{R}^M$, vector function $\gamma(v)=[\gamma_1(v)\ \cdots\ \gamma_N(v)]\in\mathbb{R}^N$ where each $\gamma_i:\mathbb{R}^M\to\mathbb{R}$, and scalar composite function $f(\gamma(v))$ with $f:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}$, we have the following partial derivatives via the chain rule:
$$\frac{∂f}{∂v_i}= \left[\frac{∂f}{∂\gamma_1}\ \cdots\ \frac{∂f}{∂\gamma_N}\right] \cdot 
\left[\frac{∂\gamma_1}{∂v_i}\ \cdots\ \frac{∂\gamma_N}{∂v_i}\right]\qquad\forall i=1,\dots,M$$

for any vector $g=[g_1\ \cdots\ g_N]\in\mathbb{R}^N$ and norm $\|g\|=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^Ng_i^2\ }$, we have partial derivatives:
$$\frac{∂‖g‖}{∂g_i}= \frac{g_i}{‖g‖}\qquad\forall i=1,\dots,N$$

for any vectors $g=[g_1\ \cdots\ g_N]\in\mathbb{R}^N$ and $h=[h_1\ \cdots\ h_N]\in\mathbb{R}^N$, and norm $\|g\|=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^Ng_i^2\ }$, we have partial derivatives:
$$\text{i)}\quad \frac{∂}{∂g_i}\left[\frac{g}{‖g‖}\cdot h\right]= \frac{h_i}{‖g‖} - \left(\frac{g}{‖g‖}\cdot h\right)\frac{g_i}{‖g‖^2}\qquad\forall i=1,\dots,N$$
$$\text{ii)}\quad \frac{∂}{∂h_i}\left[\frac{g}{‖g‖}\cdot h\right]=\frac{g_i}{‖g‖}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\ \forall i=1,\dots,N$$
$\ $


(Omitting time dependence notation from here on out)
Using the facts 1 and 2 with $f(g)=\|g\|=d$ and $g(v)=v=p-q$ gives:
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{∂d}{∂p_k} 
&= \left[\frac{∂‖g‖}{∂g_1}\ \cdots\ \frac{∂‖g‖}{∂g_3}\right] \cdot 
\left[\frac{∂(p_x-q_x)}{∂p_k}\ \cdots\ \frac{∂(p_z-q_z)}{∂p_k}\right] \\
&= \left[\frac{p_x-q_x}{d}\ \cdots\ \frac{p_z-q_z}{d}\right] \cdot 
e_k \\
&= \frac{p_k-q_k}{d}\qquad\qquad\forall k=\{x,y,z\}
\end{aligned}$$
where $e_k$ is the corresponding standard Euclidean basis (eg. $e_x=[1\ 0\ 0]$).
Using facts 1 and 3(i) with $f(g)=\frac{g}{‖g‖}\cdot h=\dot{d}$, $h = \dot{p}-\dot{q}$, and $g(v)=v=p-q$ gives:
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{∂\dot{d}}{∂p_k} 
&=\left[\frac{∂}{∂g_1}\left[\frac{g}{‖g‖}\cdot h\right]\ \cdots\ \frac{∂}{∂g_3}\left[\frac{g}{‖g‖}\cdot h\right]\right] \cdot 
\left[\frac{∂(p_x-q_x)}{∂p_k}\ \cdots\ \frac{∂(p_z-q_z)}{∂p_k}\right]\\
&= \left[ \frac{\dot{p}_x-\dot{q}_x}{d} - \left(\frac{p-q}{d}\cdot (\dot{p}-\dot{q})\right)\frac{p_x-q_x}{d^2} \ \cdots\  \frac{\dot{p}_z-\dot{q}_z}{d} - \left(\frac{p-q}{d}\cdot (\dot{p}-\dot{q})\right)\frac{p_z-q_z}{d^2} \right]
\cdot e_k \\
&= \frac{\dot{p}_k-\dot{q}_k}{d} - \left(\frac{p-q}{d}\cdot (\dot{p}-\dot{q})\right)\frac{p_k-q_k}{d^2}\qquad\qquad\forall k=\{x,y,z\}
\end{aligned}$$
Using facts 1 and 3(ii) with $f(h)=\frac{g}{‖g‖}\cdot h=\dot{d}$, $h(v) = v = \dot{p}-\dot{q}$, and $g=p-q$ gives:
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{∂\dot{d}}{∂\dot{p}_k} 
&=\left[\frac{∂}{∂h_1}\left[\frac{g}{‖g‖}\cdot h\right]\ \cdots\ \frac{∂}{∂h_3}\left[\frac{g}{‖g‖}\cdot h\right]\right] \cdot 
\left[\frac{∂(\dot{p}_x-\dot{q}_x)}{∂\dot{p}_k}\ \cdots\ \frac{∂(\dot{p}_z-\dot{q}_z)}{∂\dot{p}_k}\right]\\
&= \left[ \frac{p_x-q_x}{d}  \ \cdots\  \frac{p_z-q_z}{d} \right]
\cdot e_k \\
&= \frac{p_k-q_k}{d}\qquad\qquad\forall k=\{x,y,z\}
\end{aligned}$$
$\ $
My main concern is if fact 3(i) is correct and thus if what I've determined for the $\frac{∂\dot{d}}{∂p_k}$ are correct. Facts 1, 2, and 3(ii) seem correct. Fact 3(i) I think would need to follow a multivariate quotient rule, possibly as mentioned in the answer to Quotient rule extendable to functions of vectors?
In the application I care about, literature I've found for those partial derivates only has the simpler term to the left of the $-$ sign, not the additional more complex term. This makes me thing either: 1) 3(i) is wrong and/or I messed up, 2) they weren't as careful with their multivariate calculus, or 3) that term is so small (due to $d^{-3}$ scaling) that they just omitted it.
I would very much appreciate any help in verifying! Thank you!
